# Mongodb, Update existing data of nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to edit/update existing data of the single array, Don't understand what syntax I missed here

```
..........
    name: String,
    technologies:{
        server:[{
            name: String,
            version: Number,
            note: String,
            status: Boolean
        }]
      }
    ..........
```

**My code**

```
exports.editTechnologyPost = function(req, res){
       Project.findOneAndUpdate(  
           { "name" : req.params.name, "technologies.server._id": req.params.id  },
           { "$set": { 
            'technologies.$.server.$.name': req.body.name,
            'technologies.$.server.$.version': req.body.version,
            'technologies.$.server.$.note': req.body.note,
            'technologies.$.server.$status': req.body.status
            }   },  { new: true },  
           function(err, obj) { 
           }
       )
    }
```

Comment: `technologies` is not an array hence you cannot use `$` with it.

Comment: let me try @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: `'technologies.$.server.$.status': req.body.status` You have forgotten to add `.`dot

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet  Now worked perfectly, please post your answer